# Is it possible to comment out a line of PHP code containing special "special" characters?

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, comments

This is probably not constructive at all, and I'm asking more of curiosity than anything else, **because I know how to overcome this issue by modifying the code.**

Anyway, having this PHP line:

```
strip_tags(preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $nameXML));
```

Is there any way to comment out this **line**? (**without any modifications to it!**)
I have already tried using `//`,`/**/`, and `#` and in every case PHP has thrown a syntax error.

EDIT #1: I assume a commented line will not produce **ANY** output - if it does than it's not really commented out, is it?

EDIT #2: Please don't try too hard answering this question. It's not a real issue.

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly? Those should absolutely comment out a line of code.

Comment: How can you comment out a line of code without any modifications to it? Isn't commenting out the line a modification?

Comment: @thatidiotguy PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file - this is because of the "?>" in the regexp

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn, sorry - I only meant modifications to the actual PHP code

Comment: @Itako I think you need to show more code. All that is doing is removing HTML tags from `$nameXML` after `<br>` elements are replaced with `\n`.

Comment: But this is the line causing the "issue". And please keep in mind this is not a real issue, I'm just curious if it's not possible to comment out SOME php lines.

Comment: Well look at that http://codepad.org/s0kwJH9d

Comment: @Musa um... that's THE problem here? it should not output anything

Comment: @Musa you should have that added to the question

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting a strange output is because of the particular `?>` in your regex. In this case, PHP is interpreting that as the end of the script, because the rest of the code is commented out. To answer your question directly, in this case, you cannot comment out that particular line of code without editing it. You would have to remove the `?>` portion of the regex in order for the script to continue to run normally.

Edit:

Additionally, it *would* work if you encapsulated the comment in `/* */` according to [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php). **However**, because the regex has `*/` it is prematurely ending the block style comment, thus still breaking out of PHP mode and returning to HTML mode.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that's something I already know. Of course if no one comes up with some kind of a magical solution soon, I will accept it anyway

Comment: @Itako I've made a discovery. Please have a look at my edited answer.